# background: url and filter:brightness

Tags: html, image, css, web

I would like to darken the background image of a div with filter:brightness. It works well but obviously it darkens the whole div, not only the image. How can i do to darken only the background image with CSS ? I would like to have some white text on it.

Here is my code :

```css
#about_header {
  background: url(../img/background/spa_02.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 filter: brightness(20%);
 -webkit-filter: brightness(20%);
 -moz-filter: brightness(20%);
 -o-filter: brightness(20%);
 -ms-filter: brightness(20%);
  height:400px;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#about_header h1{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="about_header">
  <div class="container text-vcenter">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div>
          <h1>Contact us</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Use 2 separate `div`s, one as the parent with the background and the size, the other containing only the content and stretches to fill the parent.

Comment: I don't get it, could you show me with an edit of my code please ? So where shoud le filter goes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually wrong when I talked about parent and children. You have to put the containers under the same level:

```css
#about_header {
  background: url("http://www.thestatedhome.com/media/catalog/category/13514044-brown-natural-linen-texture-for-the-background-Stock-Photo.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  filter: brightness(20%);
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.text-vcenter {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.container h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="about_header"></section>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-vcenter">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div>
          <h1>Contact us</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't understand how to do it with your previous answer lol. It works well but now my text-vcenter donc work anymore.

Here is its code : .text-vcenter {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

Comment: It's ok now. Putting it on the row worked too but I prefer your answer :). Thanks for your help :).